# Find $e^{z}$ in the form of u+iv and the magnitude of $e^{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find e^{z} in the form $u + iv$

So I am trying to break this down into real and imaginary parts so I can put it into Euler's formula and find the length Generally, I'm trying to follow [this:](https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/find-ez-in-the-form-uiv-and-ez-if-z-equals-34i/)

$$f(z) = 2\pi i(1 + i)$$
$$2\pi i(1+i) = 2\pi i + 2 \pi i^2 = i(2 \pi + 2 \pi i)$$
$$= e^{0}e^{2\pi i(1+i)}$$
so applying Euler's:
$$= e^{0}(\cos{} +\sin{(2\pi + 2\pi i)})$$

but I'm stuck... my $v$ still has an $i$ in it. What can I do?

Comment: Separate real and imaginary parts as $i^2=-1$

Comment: In your first formula, what is $f$? And what is $z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First simplify it
$2\pi i (1+i) = 2\pi i  +2\pi i^2 = 2\pi i - 2\pi \\\Rightarrow e^{2\pi i -2\pi} = e^{-2\pi}(\cos 2\pi + i\sin 2\pi) = e^{-2\pi}  $

Comment: ahhhhh i^2 = -1, dammit

Answer (score 0):

If $z=x+iy$, then
$$
e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)
$$
and so $|e^z|=e^x$. You can now also find the real and imaginary parts.